# Scraping - wait untill all yielded requests are finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Hey I have just started with Scrapy. I am wrting a basic cralwer for the website [popupstore](http://www.popupstore.com.br/). This website uses an ajax request to get all data related to a single product in json format. here is my code

```
 `  def parse_item(self, response):
        self.n += 1
        print("inside parse_item => ", self.n)

        popupitem = PopupItem()
        popupitem["url"] = response.url
        item_desc_api = self.get_item_desc_api(response)
        print("url to call =>", item_desc_api)
        # calling api url to get items description
        yield scrapy.Request(item_desc_api, callback=self.parse_item_from_api,
                         meta={"popupitem": popupitem})




    def parse_item_from_api(self, response):
        self.m += 1
        print("inside parse_item_from_api =>",self.m)
        popupitem = response.meta["popupitem"]
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        yield popupitem
```

I have used two variables n and m to display how many times parse_item (n) is being called and parse_item_from_api (n) is being called

**Problem**

When I run this code it displays n -> 116 and m-> 37 only .So programs quit before processing all yielded requests and only 37 items are stored in output.JSON file. **How can i make sure that all yielded requests are processed before programs quits**

**Scrapy Logs**

```
2017-06-13 13:37:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider 
(finished)
2017-06-13 13:37:40 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json 
feed (37 items) in: out.json
2017-06-13 13:37:40 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy 
stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 93446,
'downloader/request_count': 194,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 194,
'downloader/response_bytes': 1808706,
'downloader/response_count': 194,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 193,
'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
'dupefilter/filtered': 154,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 13, 8, 37, 40, 576449),
'item_scraped_count': 37,
'log_count/DEBUG': 233,
'log_count/INFO': 8,
'request_depth_max': 3,
'response_received_count': 193,
'scheduler/dequeued': 193,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 193,
'scheduler/enqueued': 193,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 193,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 13, 8, 37, 17, 124336)}
2017-06-13 13:37:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed ( 
finished)
```

Comment: any one please help. I am stuck to dead end :(

Comment: Does your crawl log show that some requests are being filtered? Are you getting all HTTP-200 or are some requests in error (404, 500...)? this should appear in the stats at the end.

Comment: Your crawl did fetch 193 HTTP-200 responses, so all good on that front. You'll have to share your whole spider, or the whole crawl log showing that the crawl ends prematurely.

Comment: @paultrmbrth please find my whole code int he following gist https://gist.github.com/afrazahmad21/29bd47c7120b9c7ae091889db27c468c

Comment: I will personally not run your program, so I guess you'll also need to share your crawl logs with LOG_LEVEL='DEBUG'. Scrapy will not end if there are sill requests to be processed (those you have yielded in callbacks.) So make sure you are indeed yielding the correct expected number of Requests (maybe with a `self.logger.debug('yielding request to %r' % someurl)` statements.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `'dupefilter/filtered': 154,` in your stats. It means that some requests appear the "same" to Scrapy. Duplicate requests are filtered by default. You can understand which ones they are with `DUPEFILTER_DEBUG=True`. And if you really need scrapy to fetch those pages again, use `dont_filter=True` when building your `scrapy.Request` before yielding

Comment: Thanks @paultrmbrth :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of all the requests you want to make

```
all_requests = ['https://website.com/1', 'https://website.com/2', 'https://website.com/3']

link = all_requests.pop() # extract the one request to make

# make first request
yield Request(url = link, callback = self.prase_1, meta = {'remaining_links' : all_requests, data = []}

def parse_1(self, response):

    data = []

    data = data.extend( response.meta['data] ) 

    ... GRAB YOUR DATA FROM RESPONSE

    remaining_links = response.meta['remaining_links']


    # if there are more requests to make
    if len(remaining_links) > 0:
        link = remaining_links.pop() # extract one request to make

        yield Request(url = link, callback = self.prase_1, meta = {'remaining_links' : remaining_links, data = data}

    else:

        yield data
```